# Error - 'set' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Alguien sabe la raíz de este error y cual es su solución?

```
album_sales_dict = {"Back in Black: 50 Millones, The Bodyguard: 50 Millones, Thriller: 65 Millones"}

f = album_sales_dict["Thriller"]

print(f)
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-54-bd3608164ace> in <module>
> ----> 1 f = album_sales_dict["Thriller"]
>       2 print(f)
>
> TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
album_sales_dict = {"Back in Black": "50 Millones", "The Bodyguard": "50 Millones", "Thriller": "65 Millones"}
```

El error se encontraba en las comillas que van tanto en los nombres de los diccionarios como en la claves.

Comment: Exacto mi amigo, te habría respondido pero no vi tu pregunta, lo importante es que pudiste resolver tu error y aprender mas :)